# How to select CMOS register?

Tags: c, interrupt

I'm working on a monolithic kernel and am trying to implement support for the CMOS clock. After reading about the topic, I came across this line of code:

```
outb (0x70, (NMI_disable_bit << 7) | (selected CMOS register number));
```

I mostly understand what's going on except the `NMI_disable_bit` part. What does this mean in this snippet? Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bit 7 of the port 0x70, the RTC RAM index register is used, when set to 1, to disable all the sources of [NMIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-maskable_interrupt).

An NMI is an interrupt that cannot be masked by the *IF* - Interrupt flag in the R/E/FLAGS register (e.g. with the `cli` instruction) so a hardware assist is needed to disable it.
The bit 7 of the port 0x70 is negated and ANDed with all the source of NMIs (or equivalent design).

Note that the NMI pin has been replaced by the *LINT1* pin since the Pentium Pro.
When the [LAPIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller) is disabled the LINT1 pin reverts to being the NMI pin but if the LAPIC is enabled then the term NMI is a synonym for *Local Interrupt 1* and the software can program each *LINT0/1* pin to trigger various events (including, but not limiting to, an NMI).